# Haproxy redirect configuration for plex?

Tags: proxy, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, haproxy, plex

Hope someone can help me :)

I try to configure HAProxy for plex redirection but didn't found the solution yet.
So basically to run plex home page you should go to => IPADRESS:PORT/web which redirect to IPADRESS:PORT/web/index.html

I made this kind of redirect:

```
use_backend plex if { hdr_beg(Host) -i plex. }

backend plex
    server plex localhost:32400 check
```

This is ok, i can join plex => plex.mydomain.tld/web

But i would like to be able to join plex with this URL => plex.mydomain.tld

I tried to add this line:

```
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /(.*)     \1\ /web\2
```

Changing is fine, my URL switch to => plex.mydomain.tld/web/index.html

But i have a 404 ERROR...

What kind of trick i should do to acces plex from plex.mydomain.tld ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Found some info that helped me figure it out:

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 syslog
    maxconn     1000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 4096
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3 no-tls-tickets
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH


defaults
    log  global
    mode  http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    option  http-server-close
    option  forwardfor except 127.0.0.0/8
    option  redispatch
    option  contstats
    retries  3
    timeout  http-request 10s
    timeout  queue 1m
    timeout  connect 10s
    timeout  client 1m
    timeout  server 1m
    timeout  check 10s

listen stats
    bind *:9090
    mode  http
    maxconn  10
    stats  enable
    stats  hide-version
    stats  realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats  uri /
    stats  auth admin:admin

frontend ALL
    bind   *:80
    bind   *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/nomercy.myqnapcloud.com.pem crt /etc/haproxy/certs/nomercy.myqnapcloud.com.pem
    mode   http

    # Define path for lets encrypt
    acl is_letsencrypt path_beg -i /.well-known/acme-challenge/
    use_backend letsencrypt if is_letsencrypt

    # Define hosts
    acl host_website hdr(host) -i nomercy.myqnapcloud.com

    # Direct hosts to backend
    use_backend website if host_website

    # Redirect port 80 to 443
    # But do not redirect letsencrypt since it checks port 80 and not 443
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc } !is_letsencrypt

backend letsencrypt
    server letsencrypt 127.0.0.1:8888

backend website
    balance         roundrobin
    option          httpchk GET /check
    cookie          SERVERID insert indirect nocache
    http-check      expect rstring ^UP$
    default-server  inter 3s fall 3 rise 2
    server          server1 192.168.2.151:8888 check
    server          server2 192.168.2.152:8888 check
    server          server3 192.168.2.153:8888 check


listen plex
    bind *:32400 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/nomercy.myqnapcloud.com.pem crt /etc/haproxy/certs/nomercy.myqnapcloud.com.pem
    balance         roundrobin
    option          httpchk GET /check
    http-check      expect rstring ^UP$
    default-server  inter 3s fall 3 rise 2
    server          server1 192.168.2.149:32400 check port 8888
    server          server2 192.168.2.148:32400 check port 8888
    server          server3 192.168.2.147:32400 check port 8888
```

You can remove the ssl credentials if you don't have it installed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here unfortunately has nothing to do with your HAProxy configuration. Instead it is Plex that is causing the issue.

**Example**

With your configuration, when you go to `plex.mydomain.tld` HAProxy is adding in the `/web` and as a result Plex gets the following url: `plex.mydomain.tld/web`. This is correct however Plex will then want to forward the browser on to `plex.mydomain.tld/web/index.html`. But when the browser sends a request or that url, HAProxy steps in and adds that extra `/web` again and the resulting url that is set to Plex is `plex.mydomain.tld/web/web/index.html` which doesn't exist and hence the 404 error you got.

While going to `plex.mydomain.tld/index.html` may work, I assume all links from that page to any other page won't work due to the say issue.

**To solve this you could**

1. Look through Plex's configuration to see if it is possible to run it with out the `/web`.
2. Taking inspiration from [here](https://gist.github.com/spikegrobstein/4384954), you could configure HAProxy something like this:

   ```
   frontend http
       mode http
       bind *:80

       acl plex hdr_beg(Host) -i plex.
       acl root_dir path_reg ^$|^/$
       acl no_plex_header req.hdr_cnt(X-Plex-Device-Name) -i 0

       redirect location http://plex.mydomain.tld/web/index.html 301 if no_plex_header root_dir plex
       use_backend plex if plex

   backend plex
       server plex localhost:32400 check
   ```

   The key difference being the `redirect location` line which will redirect from `/` to `/web/index.html` if the header `X-Plex-Device-Name` isn't set. The reason you have to check for the header is that it appears that plex uses `/` for something else.

   Note: This config is an example and I haven't tested this at all

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I want to echo that I used the solution provided by JamesStewy and it worked, with the minor correction;

```
redirect location http://plex.mydomain.tld/web/index.html code 301 if no_plex_header root_dir plex
```

At least, that was necessary for me (running haproxy 1.7.2).